# XPages Ckeditor is not rendered on Android

Tags: ckeditor, xpages, lotus-notes

I would like to use the Ckeditor on an Android device.
But also with this simple example it does not work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:inputRichText id="inputRichText1"></xp:inputRichText>
</xp:view>
```

I only got a tiny with textarea. There are no errors or something like this.
I use Android 5.1.1 with Chrome. My Server is Domino V9.0.1 FP4.
I got no problems on iOS Devices and also no Problems on the Desktop.

This problem is reproducible with the Chrome Mobile Development Tools.

Did i miss an option that says: not render on Android?

Comment: Older versions of CKEditor are not out-of-the-box compatible with Chrome on Android; see [the compatibility page](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_browsers-section-a-word-about-mobile-environments) for info on how to enable rendering (or take a chance on upgrading the editor version).

Comment: Sadly, I can't update the CKEditor, any other chance to get it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this problem i just have to set

```
CKEDITOR.env.isCompatible = true;
```